# Functions with parametrised arity

Tags: templates, haskell, factory-pattern

Is it possible to write functions that returns functions whose signature depends on the arguments to the builder function?

Specifically I am refining an implementation of primitive recursion I wrote. I want to have factory like functions that for numeric parameters generate a function that works on tuples or lists of the length equal to the arguments passed for the numeric parameters. Currently I am handling cases like `pr 1 2 [0,5,13]`, which is an invalid statement from the perspective of primitive recursion, at runtime through `Either`:

```
pr :: (Show a) => Int -> Int -> [a] -> Either String a
pr i k args
  | 1 <= i && i <= k && length args == k = Right $ args!!(i-1)
  | i <= 0 = Left "first argument of pr needs to be greater or equal to 1"
  | k < i = Left "first argument of pr needs to be lesser or equal to the second argument"
  | length args /= k = Left $ "pr expected "++(show k)++" arguments, got "++(show $ length args)++": pr "++(concat[show i, " ", show k, " ", show args])
```

But I would like to somehow catch that case at compile time, as from the perspective of the formal system I want to implement with this, this is a compile time error -- passing more arguments to a function than its domain specifies.

Is this somehow possible and if not what would be the correct approach to get compile time errors for what should be invalid statements.

Comment: Every function has arity 1 in Haskell...

Comment: sure, but you can work with tuples to simulate fixed arities.

Comment: And to answer your question, it is possible to have functions where the "arity" (although that is definitely not the good word) depends on the *type* of the parameter, but *not* the value.

Comment: no, you can use *lists* for that. But tuples have a fixed type at *compile* time.

Comment: you mean like `x1:x2:x3:[]` to enforce 3 arguments via a list of length 3? How would you parametrise that pattern on `k` (the second parameter of `pr`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a sized vector. It is like a list but in addition to the type of its elements, it is also parametrised by type level natural numbers.

[sized-vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-vector-1.4.3.1/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html) package on Hackage is what you need. As it happens, the function you're trying to implement is the `last` function in this library.

Note that every time you call `last` you will have to prove the compiler that its argument vector is of size at least 1. You can do this by constructing the vector in the source code (for example, the compiler will understand `1 :- 2 :- Nil` is of size 2) or if the vector is obtained at runtime perhaps by conversion from a list, you'll have to write a function that either gives a run time error if it has no elements or constructs a vector of size at least one i.e. have the type level size `S n` for some `n`.

If you're not familiar with dependently typed programming (a paradigm that includes this and much much more) I suggest you look through some tutorials first.  For example, [this post](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/konn/prove-your-haskell-for-great-safety/dependent-types-in-haskell) is a good example that includes how to implement vectors from scratch and write functions for them.

A word of caution, learning and using dependently typed programming is exciting, addictive, but also time consuming. So if you want to focus on the task at hand, you might like to live with runtime checks for now.